# ignore //abi table comment

Tags: table, abi

I have general header, which I wanna include in different contracts:

ent.h:

```
//@abi table entities i64
struct entity {
    entity() {};
    uint64_t id;    
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
    EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( entity, (id))
};
```

I need table "entities" in abi only in one contract, and don't need in second. 
I've tried macros:

```
#define GEN_TABLE
#ifdef GEN_TABLE
//@abi table entities i64
#endif //that's not work. Table isn't generate
struct entity {
    entity() {};
    uint64_t id;    
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
    EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( entity, (id))
};
```

and tried post struct definition:

```
struct entity {
    entity() {};
    uint64_t id;    
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
    EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( entity, (id))
};
...
cpp:
//@abi table entities i64
struct entity; //doesn't generate table
```

It didn't help.

Is it possible to do it without copy-paste code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. There's no way to do it with eosiocpp, but it will be removed in feature releases.

To do that trick with eosio.cdt just use macroses:

```
#define INC_TO_BUILD
#ifdef INC_TO_BUILD
#define ABI_TABLE [[eosio::table]]
#define ABI_ACTION [[eosio::action]]
#else
#define ABI_TABLE
#define ABI_ACTION
#endif // INC_TO_BUILD
...
struct ABI_TABLE state {...}
```

If u need to use name parameter, u can use that:

```
#define INC_TO_BUILD
#ifdef INC_TO_BUILD
#define ABI_TABLE(...) [[eosio::table(#__VA_ARGS__)]]
#define ABI_ACTION [[eosio::action]]
#else
#define ABI_TABLE(...)
#define ABI_ACTION
#endif // INC_TO_BUILD
...
struct ABI_TABLE(entities) entity {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Macros should work, but you'd have to edit the `eosiocpp` script in order to be able to use them when you compile the code. You can't just do `eosiocpp -DGEN_TABLE` like in normal c++.

Comment: They don't work. If I have some code after comment with abi, it wouldn't generate... Look example: #define tst
#ifdef tst
//@abi table entities i64
#endif // tst

Comment: Can you be more specific about why they don't work? What exactly did you try to do to use precompilation defines?

Comment: I didn't modify eosiocpp, but I predefined in code #define GEN_TABLE before ifdef, so //abi... was included to build, but abi table didn't generate. Or is it some difference between predefine in code and predefine in build? Look at second codesinppet in question, I modified it. Thank u anyway!

Comment: Ah I get what you mean now. I'm not sure, but it could be that the `//@abi` part has to be directly above the table, and if you use these preprocessor directives, then it appears 2 lines above with a blank line inbetween. Trydoing the `//@abi...` part followed on the same line by `#endif`?

Comment: I don't see a way to do it, abi comment starts with //, so it cannot ends with #ifdef. U cannot write abi comment after #endif cause it will not have any sense... Or am I missing your idea?

Comment: Sorry you're right. I've not had my morning coffee yet...

Comment: it's OK :D have a nice day